# Why does my WebGL context only have a subset of extensions

Tags: webgl

I'm working on a rewrite of some of the rendering internals of an existing WebGL application. All of a sudden, the `WEBGL_depth_texture` extension is no longer available within my rendering context (which is inconvenient, as I need it for this particular application).

If I open up antother tab in the same browser (*Chrome 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)*) and look at the WebGL Caps Viewer (http://www.geeks3d.com/webgl/), I see the proper set of *24* extensions including `WEBGL_depth_texture`.

In my own application, I now have a meagre subset of *9* extensions available to me.

I obviously broke something, but how do I investigate what is wrong?

Comment: Ok, looks like a dud. Chrome was updating itself when I went to the about page. I'm now on 59.0.3071.104 and the problem seems to have disappeared. I'll will play around a bit and then probably close the question.

Comment: Oh, figured it out, I was running a WebGL debugger that replaced the web gl context. Obvious in hindsight, but a good enough pitfall to warrant a Q&A entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running [Ben Vanik's WebGL Inspector](https://benvanik.github.io/WebGL-Inspector/). Which is an excellent debugging tool for WebGL, but as it takes over the WebGL context (as such debuggers need to do in order to function) it *does* mess with the available extensions.

Comment: It's open source, you could try to fix it ;)  Added a few WebGL2 things [here](https://github.com/greggman/WebGL-Inspector)